# Design of a simple job quote system

Tags: c#, sql-server, oop

What would be the best way to implement a simple quote system to determine a job cost based on two attributes *type* and *value*.

The job cost would determined what range the *value* falls into for it's *type*.

For example:

Job type A would cost

- $ 80 for value between $  0-150
- $100 for value between $150-300
- $120 for value > $300

Job type B would cost

- $ 50 for value between  $  0-120
- $100 for value between  $120-250
- $120 for value between  $120-500
- $150 for value > $500

The band range should be configurable and each job *type* can have different range of bands.

The band ranges and costs may change and would ultimately be stored in a SQL server database accessed through a repository pattern so I could implement mock repository for TDD.

My initial development led me to having a lightweight class below representing the bands

```
public class JobCostBand
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public float ValueLowerBand { get; set; }
    public float ValueUpperBand { get; set; }
    public float Cost { get; set; }
}
```

I had a mock repository using LINQ to select from a in memory list of these objects to return the costs. This class would map easily enough to a SQL table whereby I could use LINQ to SQL find the cost in my final DB repository.

My problem was what to do with last band for a given job *type*. I started off using *float.MaxValue* for the upper band but that didn't sit well with me. I then thought about using either a upper or lower value to specify the band in the JobCostClass but again this didn't sit well. Am I thinking too much about this or have I missed a real simple way of modelling this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The job you're trying to do is map an input value to a band. How you represent it is a secondary matter. So you should really be concentrating on an object that is able to return the correct band for a given input value.

I'd stick with representing only an upper or lower band for each `JobCostBand`. Also have a nullable value for upper band in case the given band's upper value is lower than the next band's lower value. Have a 'manager' object which keeps the collection of bands, and which is able to query them in response to a value and decide which is the most appropriate. I would store these in a sorted list (ordered by lower band threshold), and iterate through the array in order until the band matches.

Comment: Good point about thinking about what I am trying to do - easy to get bogged down the representation. Don't fully understand the nullable value point, I understand the need to check that upper value level in respect to the next band but how would the nullable value help that? I suppose the nullable value would solve the smell of float.maxvalue and my manager would then take care of the highest band where there is potentially no limit.

Comment: Yes. You'd use `null` if there wasn't an upper value, which may or may not be the case depending on your domain.